# Is this painting based on a real painting?

Tags: set-design, fantastic-mr-fox

In *Fantastic Mr. Fox*, Fox stands in front of a painting with a bunch of badgers standing around (pictured behind him in this still). Is it a parody with badgers of a real painting? Or is it simply stylized to look like a certain era?

[image: Mr. Fox stands in front of a badger-filled painting]

Comment: The painting looks familiar, so my best bet is that it is a parody of a famous painting. It also could be a joke because I do not think that foxes and badgers get along, and there he is standing in front of a painting with a bunch of badgers in the home of a badger

Comment: Reminiscent of US Civil War art but couldn't name a specific picture

Answer (score 2):

I think the posing is more reminiscent of photos from the Civil War era, like this one of the Buffalo Soldiers:
[image: Buffalo Soldiers black and white photo standing on a hill]

But the actually style of painting is pulled from Winslow Homer, one of the prominent painters from the Civil War:
[image]

I think the combination of references people are familiar with is pretty effective at making you feel like it’s a painting you know, while making something new and original!

Comment: Probably not. They are wearing kilts.  Obviously a Scots regiment.